# Searching multiple values

Tags: php, html, search

So far i have created a search box, which searches the primary key of my database.

How can i modify my php query to search multiple values in my database.

eg: If i search the name of the car instead of the VIN (primary key) it will show all the results matching the search value. 
This

```
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE VIN='$VIN'");
```

This is my form :

```
<form name="search" action="http://www.deakin.edu.au/~sjrem/SIT104_3/cars.php" method="post">
<h2> Search for a car of your choice </h2>   


<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="VIN" /> </td>
</tr>

</table> 



                       <p>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="search" />
</FORM>
```

Comment: Could you confirm what Database provider you are using. Answers will vary based on your answer.

Comment: do you have an input field for every different search facet or a common one?

Comment: This is a SQL question not PHP. But you could use LIKE for your query or if you have an exact name of the cars you can search for that as well just like you did with vin.

Comment: Problem with all the answers so far, is it sounds like OP wants to check all relevant columns against the search field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like `$query = ("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE VIN='$VIN' OR name LIKE '%$VIN%'");`?

"LIKE" uses % as wildcard, so it will find all cars that have $VIN in their name.

But anyway make sure to `mysql_real_escape_string()` your parameter $VIN first, to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: Tried that, but i get errors on line 66 : OCIExecute($stmt);?>

Comment: and line 84: while(OCIFetch($stmt)) {

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Name LIKE '%$txtName%'");
```

**NOTE:**: Wildcard `%` is been used at the beginning and end to return all names having your search word anywhere in the field.

Comment: This one is working, however it brings up my whole list not doesnt sort the search. eg: if i search Nissan Skyline , it will bring up all the results as well as Nissan silvia, and Subaru etc.

I only want it to bring up nissan skyline

Comment: I get it. For exact search remove the % from both ends of the $txtName

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work for you

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE VIN='$VIN' OR CARS='$VIN'");
```